# Code coverage of Meteor application after deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, istanbul, nyc

Meteor application has built with 'meteor build' command and then deployed. After deployment application runs using plain node command 'node bundle/main.js'.
Running nyc using command 'nyc node main.js'  only give the partial results from the meteor generate files.

**Code coverage result**

[image]

Is there anyway to get the full code coverage results? I am only interested to get result about javascript files.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please why you intend to get the code coverage of your deployment code and not of your development code? Although this is interesting because Meteor should ignore all test related files at building stage. Do you have written any test functions that are not declared inside an external file but inside the same file of your code?

Comment: @Jankapunkt, I am working on a legacy product which has undergone massive changes. All old test cases are broken and new tests have not added. Because of these changes a lot of dead code is now present in the code base and my intend is to remove this dead code. If I can get the code coverage on deployment environment using end to end tests done by validation team, I will be sure of which code can be removed easily.